# Regex Powershell shows too much

Tags: regex, powershell

I am new to powershell. I am trying to automate my work a bit and need simple extraction of following pattern from all filetypes:

```regex
([0-9A-Z]{2,4}.[0-9A-Z]{8}.[0-9A-Z]{8}.[0-9A-Z]{4})
```

Example:

```
*lots of text*
X-xdaemon-transaction-id: string=9971.0A67341C.6147B834.0043,ee=3,shh,rec=0.0,recu=0.0,reid=0.0,cu=3,cld=1
X-xdaemon-transaction-id: string=AA71.0A67341C.6147B442.0043,ee=3,shh,rec=0.0,recu=0.0,reip=0.0,cu=3,cld=1
*lots of text*
```

Unfortunately, I am receiving output like this:

```
1mAAAA-0005nG-TN-H:220: 
X-xdaemon-transaction-id: string=AA71.0A67341C.6147B442.0043,ee=3,shh,rec=0.0,recu=0.0,reip=0.0,cu=3,cld=1
```

my 'code' is as following:

```
Select-String -Path C:\Samples\* -Pattern "(0001.[0-9A-Z]{8}.[0-9A-Z]{8}.[0-9A-Z]{4})" -CaseSensitive
```

And I'd like to receive only the patterns: `AA71.0A67341C.6147B442.0043` without anything added

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try `'\b[0-9A-Z]{2,4}\.[0-9A-Z]{8}\.[0-9A-Z]{8}\.[0-9A-Z]{4}\b'`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for fast reply. Unfortunately, same result :(
Powershell adds additional information about the file where he found it, row and whole line to the matched pattern.

`PS C:\Xray\> Select-String -Path C:\Xray\* -Pattern '\b[0-9A-Z]{4}\.[0-9A-Z]{8}\.[0-9A-Z]{8}\.[0-9A-Z]{4}\b' -CaseSensitive`

Output:

`1mAAAA-0005nG-TN-H:220: 
X-xdaemon-transaction-id: string=AA71.0A67341C.6147B442.0043,ee=3,shh,rec=0.0,recu=0.0,reip=0.0,cu=3,cld=1`

Comment: `Select-String` returns `MatchInfo` objects. I commend to your attention the Microsoft Docs on [`Select-String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.1) and [the `MatchInfo` class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0). You may want to consider whether using the [`-match` operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1) would be more suitable for your needs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your regex, it's much better than mine. I have found how to do the thing I asked:

I had to create an environment variable

$B = Select-String -Path C:\Samples\* -Pattern '\b[0-9A-Z]{2,4}\.[0-9A-Z]{8}\.[0-9A-Z]{8}\.[0-9A-Z]{4}\b' -CaseSensitive -Value

$B.Matches.Value

and it gives me te result I looked for

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$rx = '\b[0-9A-Z]{2,4}\.[0-9A-Z]{8}\.[0-9A-Z]{8}\.[0-9A-Z]{4}\b'
Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $rx -Path 'C:\Samples\*' -CaseSensitive | % { $_.matches.value }
```

That is,

1. Add word boundaries to match your expected strings as whole words and escape the literal `.`  chars
2. Use `-AllMatches` (to get multiple matches per line if any) and access each resulting object match value with `$_.matches.value`.

PS test:

```
PS C:\Users\admin> $B = Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern '\b[0-9A-Z]{2,4}\.[0-9A-Z]{8}\.[0-9A-Z]{8}\.[0-9A-Z]{4}\b' -Path 'C:\Samples\*' -CaseSensitive | % { $_.matches.value }
PS C:\Users\admin> $B
9971.0A67341C.6147B834.0043
AA71.0A67341C.6147B442.0043
PS C:\Users\admin>
```

Comment: Nice, but note that you only need `-AllMatches` if you want to find multiple matches _per line_.

Answer (score 0):

try:

$find = Get-ChildItem *.txt | Select-String -Pattern '\b[0-9A-Z]{2,4}.[0-9A-Z]{8}.[0-9A-Z]{8}.[0-9A-Z]{4}\b' -CaseSensitive

$find.Matches.Value